# PHP XML reversed array sizeof() and count() returns incorrect values

Tags: php, xml

I've been trying to figure out why my code, as simple as it is, does not work the way i want it to.

The problem i'm having is getting the correct values when trying to check sizeof() or count() on reversed simplexml array. I'm making a comments form that stores the comments to comments.xml, then reads the 5 newest comments and lists them newest on top, oldest on bottom.

What i have inside the comments.xml:

```
<root>
 <entry>
  <name>Admin</name>
  <comment>Some nice comment</comment>
  <postedOn>07.07.2013</postedOn>
  <postedBy>***.***.***.***</postedBy>
 </entry>
</root>
```

What i have inside my .php:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("comments.xml");

$reverseArray = (array) $xml;
$reverseArray = array_reverse($reverseArray["entry"]);
$limit = sizeof($reverseArray);
//$limit = count($reverseArray);

if($limit > 5){ $limit = 5; }

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $limit; $i++){
    echo "<div class='panel'>";
    echo "<span style='float: right;'>" . $reverseArray[$i]->postedOn . "</span>";
    echo "<span style='float: left;'>" . $reverseArray[$i]->name . "</span>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $reverseArray[$i]->comment;
    echo "<br></div>";
}

?>
```

Now the problem is, when i use this with only 1 entry inside comments.xml, it does not read it, and prints nothing on the page. Whenever i add another entry, it shows them both.

I also tried to add a "No comments yet."-code before the $limit-check:

```
if($limit == 0){ echo "<div class='panel'>No comments. :(</div>";}
```

And it was visible until the second comment was posted.

I hope someone could help me out with this, running out of ideas.

edit:
I tried to run the same code without reversing the array and it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build a workaround since the sizeof()/count() did not work well with array_reverse, and here is what it looks like now:

```
<?php
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("comments.xml");
$limit = count($xmlfile->entry);

if($limit == 0){ echo "<div class='panel'>No comments. :(</div>";}

if($limit == 1){
    echo "<div class='panel'>";
    echo "<span style='float: right;'>" . $xmlfile->entry[0]->postedOn . "</span>";
    echo "<span style='float: left;'>" . $xmlfile->entry[0]->name . "</span>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $xmlfile->entry[0]->comment;
    echo "<br></div>";  
}else{
    $reverseArray = (array) $xmlfile;
    $reverseArray = array_reverse($reverseArray["entry"]);

    if($limit > 5){ $limit = 5; }

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $limit; $i++){
        echo "<div class='panel'>";
        echo "<span style='float: right;'>" . $reverseArray[$i]->postedOn . "</span>";
        echo "<span style='float: left;'>" . $reverseArray[$i]->name . "</span>";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo $reverseArray[$i]->comment;
        echo "<br></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

So i had to make it process a single entry as non-reversed. Hope this helps others who struggle with this!